# Capitalize start of certain words in optional string

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am using Parse as a back end for my application.
I am currently working on the register view and I have come across this problem.
Here is my code:

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { 
        (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in 
        if error == nil { 
            // Hooray! Let them use the app now. 
        } else {
            var errorCode = error.userInfo!["error"] as NSString
            var alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: errorCode, preferredStyle: .Alert)
            var okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil) 
            alertController.addAction(okButton) 
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Ok as you can see, if there is a problem a NSError will be created and stored in variable error. Now by default whatever error is stored in there is all lower caps.

How would I capitalise the start of the string when I don't know what's it going to be.
for example the current string would be something like
'the username bob2211 is already taken'
What I'm looking for
'The username bob2211 is already taken.'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the first character, capitalize it, and then replace the first character with the new capitalized one. I think this should be close,

```
        var errorCode = error.userInfo!["error"] as NSString
        var firstLetter = errorCode.substringToIndex(1)
        firstLetter = firstLetter.uppercaseString
        errorCode = errorCode.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(NSMakeRange(0, 1), withString: firstLetter)
```